# Why does the Wiener filter reduce only noise in my case? it is not reducing blur amount

Tags: image-processing, signal-processing

I am implementing Wiener filtering in Python, which is applied on an image blurred using disk shape point spread function. I am including code of making disk shape PSF and Wiener filter

```
def wienerFiltering(kernel,K_const,image):
    #F(u,v)
    copy_img= np.copy(image)
    image_fft =np.fft.fft2(copy_img)
    #H(u,v)
    kernel_fft  = np.fft.fft2(kernel,s=copy_img.shape)
    #H_mag(u,v)
    kernel_fft_mag = np.abs(kernel_fft)
    #H*(u,v)
    kernel_conj = np.conj(kernel_fft)

    f = (kernel_conj)/(kernel_fft_mag**2 + K_const)
    return np.abs(np.fft.ifft2(image_fft*f))


def makeDiskShape(arr,radius,centrX,centrY):
    for i in range(centrX-radius,centrX+radius):
        for j in range(centrY-radius,centrY+radius):
            if(l2dist(centrX,centrY,i,j)<=radius):
                arr[i][j]=1
    return arr/np.sum(arr)
```

This is blurred and gaussian noised image:
[image: this is blurred and gaussian noised image]

This is what I am getting result after Wiener filtering for K value of 50:
[image: this is what I am getting result after Wiener filtering for K value of 50]

The result does not seem very good, how can I improve it?

It seems noise is reduced, but amount of blur is not. Shape of disk PSF matrix is 20,20 and radius is 9 which looks like [image: this].

**Update**
Using power spectrum of ground truth image and noise to calculate K constant value, still I am getting strong artifacts:
[this is noised and blurred image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/46cUd.jpg) , [this is result after using power specturm in place of a constant K value](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Ew08v.jpg)

Comment: the guy's name is Norbert Wiener, not weiner...

Comment: @Piglet thanku for useful information

Answer (score 1):

Reduce your value of `K`. You need to play around with it until you get good results. If it's too large it doesn't filter, if it's too small you get strong artifacts.

If you have knowledge of the noise variance, you can use that to estimate the regularization parameter. In the Wiener filter, the constant `K` is a simplification of `N/S`, where `N` is the noise power and `S` is the signal power. Both these values are frequency-dependent. The signal power `S` can be estimated by the Fourier transform of the autocorrelation function of the image to be filtered. The noise power is hard to estimate, but if you have such an estimate (or know it because you created the noisy image synthetically), then you can plug that value into the equation. Note that this is the noise power, not the variance of the noise.

The following code uses [DIPlib](https://diplib.org) (the Python interface we call PyDIP) to demonstrate Wiener deconvolution (disclaimer: I'm an author). I don't think it is hard to convert this code to use other libraries.

```py
import PyDIP as dip

image = dip.ImageRead('trui.ics');
kernel = dip.CreateGauss([3,3]).Pad(image.Sizes())

smooth = dip.ConvolveFT(image, kernel)
smooth = dip.GaussianNoise(smooth, 5.0)  # variance = 5.0

H = dip.FourierTransform(kernel)
F = dip.FourierTransform(smooth)
S = dip.SquareModulus(F)  # signal power estimate
N = dip.Image(5.0 * smooth.NumberOfPixels())  # noise power (has same value at all frequencies)

Hinv = dip.Conjugate(H) / ( dip.SquareModulus(H) + N / S )

out = dip.FourierTransform(F * Hinv, {"inverse", "real"})
```

The `smooth` image looks like this:

[image: smooth]

The `out` image that comes from deconvolving the image above looks like this:

[image: out]

Don't expect a perfect result. The regularization term impedes a perfect inverse filtering because such filtering would enhance the noise so strongly that it would swamp the signal and produce a totally useless output. The Wiener filter finds a middle ground between undoing the convolution and suppressing the noise.

The DIPlib documentation for [`WienerDeconvolution`](https://diplib.org/diplib-docs/deconvolution.html#dip-WienerDeconvolution-dip-Image-CL-dip-Image-CL-dip-Image-CL-dip-Image-CL-dip-Image-L-dip-StringSet-CL) explains some of the equations involved.

Comment: yaa thats what i was facing right now, but how do you actually get good approximation of K value, and since it is a ratio of power spectrum of noise and ground truth image (i.e |F(u,v)|), since right now i do have original picture so if i do this way getting ratio of both power spectrum(not assuming constant value in formula), still i am getting strong artifacts in image,, why would be that?

Comment: @Bunny: The original picture doesn't tell you what the noise level is. You need to guess.

Comment: yaa i understand that..actually i am playing with images, i have a original image without any noise..i convolve it with point spread function to blur it so i have the true H(u,v) and i add gaussian noise to it so now i have N(u,v)

Comment: @Bunny: See my edit for how to properly account for the known noise power. Using the actual noise in the equation is not useful, you just want its statistics.